# Is being lazy a sin?

Tags: dharma, sin

By being lazy , one suffers much loss in his life.

But is being lazy also sinful ? By being lazy we don't harm anyone but can it be considered as sin ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I haven't encountered an explicit canonical verse that says being lazy is a sin.

However,

According to Śrīmad Bhagavad-Gītā , being lazy is a typical characteristic of mode of  Tamas.

> अयुक्तः प्राकृतः स्तब्धः शठो नैष्कृतिकोऽलसः।
>  विषादी दीर्घसूत्री च
> कर्ता तामस उच्यते ॥ 18.28 ॥
>
> > 28. Unsteady, vulgar, unbending, cheating, malicious, lazy, desponding and procrastinating such an agent is called Tamasic
>
> [English Translation](https://www.dlshq.org/download/bhagavad-gita/#_VPID_27) By Swami Sivananda

---

Patanjali's Yoga Sutras [Samādhi-pāda: 30-31](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115486.html) says laziness (both mental & physical) to be obstacles to knowledge, which ultimately results in grief.

---

Yājñavalkya Smṛti (3.219).—

> ‘**A man becomes degraded by omitting to do what is enjoined**, by doing
> what is condemned, and by not controlling the senses.

Not doing what ought to be done is a sign of sloth or laziness, as as such is declared to make such a person degraded.

Further, Manusmṛti [Verse 5.3-4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200377.html) defines laziness as one of the reasons for premature death

---

Finally, the Bhāgvatam says -

> [ŚB 1.1.10](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/1/10/?query=Laziness%20#bb13478)
>
> प्रायेणाल्पायुष: सभ्य कलावस्मिन् युगे जना: । मन्दा: सुमन्दमतयो
> मन्दभाग्या ह्युपद्रुता: ॥ १० ॥
>
> > 10. O learned one, in this iron Age of Kali men almost always have but short lives. They are quarrelsome, lazy, misguided, unlucky and, above
> >     all, always disturbed.

---

So, being Lazy (Ālasya) although a typical characteristic of Tamasika mode, as such might not be categorically considered a sin by itself, it's more like a duṣvṛtti (दुष्वृत्ति), as they say in a famous subhāṣita-maxim, `Laziness is verily the great enemy residing in our body (आलस्यं हि मनुष्याणां शरीरस्थो महान् रिपुः)`.

However, being lazy under certain circumstances may lead to a sin.

For example, if out of "laziness", a dvija deliberately stops performing sandhya-vandanam, or any person stops adhering to their prescribed dharma, then in that case, "being lazy indirectly make the person degraded, as we see from the Yajñavalkya Smriti verse, and therefore, in that way laziness will become sinful".